# Are FCM topics name globally unique?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

We can create a topic to send a push notification to more than one user at the same time with the following request:

`POST: https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/IID_TOKEN/rel/topics/TOPIC_NAME`

Plus the headers:
`Authorization: key=YOUR_API_KEY`

If, for example, I name a topic "topic", it's quite a common name and surely someone else must have done the same before. Am I sharing the same topic with other people, or are these topics that I "created" mine based on my API Key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging names are scoped to your project. So your topic names won't conflict with topic names in other projects, but they will need to be unique within your project.